# Windows Multipoint takes port 80

Tags: windows, windows-server, multipoint

In a Windows Server 2016 Standard,
I had to install Multipont to add licenses

But Multipoint takes the port 80

With the following command

```
netsh http show servicestate
```

you can see

```
Server session ID: FF00000520000001
Version: 2.0
State: Active
Properties:
    Max bandwidth: 4294967295
    Timeouts:
        Entity body timeout (secs): 120
        Drain entity body timeout (secs): 120
        Request queue timeout (secs): 120
        Idle connection timeout (secs): 120
        Header wait timeout (secs): 120
        Minimum send rate (bytes/sec): 150
URL groups:
URL group ID: FE00000540000001
    State: Active
    Request queue name: Request queue is unnamed.
    Properties:
        Max bandwidth: inherited
        Max connections: inherited
        Timeouts:
            Timeout values inherited
        Number of registered URLs: 1
        Registered URLs:
            HTTP://+:80/MULTIPOINT/IMULTIPOINTCERTIFICATEREQUEST/
```

How can I change the port number?

Comment: What are you wanting to run on port 80? Note that Multipoint Server is using Windows' `HTTP.SYS` driver so *it can share port 80* with other HTTP.SYS-aware programs including IIS. So if you're running IIS you don't need to do anything - you only need to change things if you're running another server on port 80 like Apache or Nginx.

Comment: I am Running Apache :(